# Maximum solar power on moon

Tags: estimation, moon, solar-cells

What is the maximum power that could be generated by covering the moon in solar panels?
Assume the entire lunar surface is covered and that the currently most efficient solar panels are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon)'s radius is 1.74 Mm (megametres). Hence by $\pi r^2$, it has about 9.48 × 10<sup>12</sup> m<sup>2</sup> of area exposed to the sun.

The Moon's apogee (furthest distance from Earth) is 405 Mm. The Earth's perihelion (closest distance to Sun) is 147 095 Mm. So the closest that the Moon is from the Sun is about 146 690 Mm.

The [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) is 1368 W/m<sup>2</sup> at a distance of 1 AU ≈ 149 598 Mm. By the inverse square law, the power at 146 690 Mm would be that multipled by (149598/146690)<sup>2</sup>, resulting in 1423 W/m<sup>2</sup>.

The world record for [solar cell efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_cell_efficiency) is 47.1% in year 2019. With this figure, we can generate 9.48 × 10<sup>12</sup> m<sup>2</sup> × 1423 W/m<sup>2</sup> × 47.1% = 6.35 PW (petawatts) of electrical power over the whole sunlit surface of the Moon.